# Sequelize query on JSONB array

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb, postgresql-11

This is the JSONB array data type in the model and `postgres` database:

```
.
.
.
      MyField: {
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSONB),
        allowNull: false
      }
.
.
.
```

The table field contains JSONB values:

```
{"{\"LessonId\": \"1\", \"TeacherId\": \"1\"}"}
```

And this is my where clause in sequelize findAll method:

```
      where: {
        MyField: {
          [Op.contains]: [
            {
              TeacherId: '1',
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

The generated query is this:

```
SELECT
    ...
    "MyField",
FROM
    "MyTable" AS "MyTable" 
WHERE
    "MyTable"."MyField" @> ARRAY [ '{"TeacherId":"1"}' ]:: JSONB [];
```

And the result set is empty. But when i include `LessonId` too, it will do my answer.
I found postgres sees the jsonb object like a String text. What is the correct way to query based on specific key in JSONB ARRAY?

Comment: Was you able to resolve this?

Comment: @NightShift how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your based field in `ARRAY` type and the operations you are trying to achieve is supported only in `JSONB` field type. You can simply define the model attribute as `JSONB` and you can still store the JSON Array inside it and run containment operations

Answer (score 0):

How about like this ?

```
where: {
        MyField: {
            [Op.contains]: {
                type: [
                    {
                        TeacherId: '1'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`@>` operator only works for comparing JSONB objects to JSONB arrays, like in this case, `{"TeacherId":"1"}` is being compared to whole JSONB array. So, in order to get `{TeacherId":"1"}` from JSONB object, you need to use `->` operator. Here is the code snippet:

```
WHERE "MyTable"."MyField" -> 'TeacherId' = '1';
```

Hope this helps